# Morphing <INPUT> in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input box

```
<input style="width: 570px;" id="storagememory" min="0" max="9999" type="text">
```

At first it might look odd, having a min and max in there.  But you see, I have the following Javascript that changes it thus:

```
document.getElementById('storagememory').addEventListener('blur', function()
{document.getElementById('storagememory').setAttribute('type','text');
 document.getElementById('storagememory').value = document.getElementById('storagememory').value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
});
document.getElementById('storagememory').addEventListener('focus', function()
{document.getElementById('storagememory').value = document.getElementById('storagememory').value.toString().replace(/\D/g,'');
 document.getElementById('storagememory').setAttribute('type','number');
});
```

So when the input is being focused on, it becomes an input/number.  This is so the min and max values are respected, and I get the UI up/down (both as buttons and as up/down keystrokes).  When the focus is lost, it becomes input/text so I can format it appropriately with comma separation on the thousands, millions, etc.

The problem lies when the input is focused in on, I lose the capability (Firefox 30.0) to type numbers into it.

My question is, how do I regain the ability to type numbers into this field without losing the ability to display non-numeric data when it's not being focused on?

The expected value of this field is an integer between 0 and 9999.  The integer is to show the proper comma separation if the value is above 999.  Decimals are not to be considered herein...as such I could very well put a parseInt() in the 'blur' to truncate any user-input that would generate a decimal point.

Thank you for reading, and for any constructive suggestions you may have on this topic.

Comment: Perhaps display the non-numeric data in a div overlaid on top of the input tag?  Then, hide/show that div as needed.   Then, the input just does what it's good at and the div can display anything you want when focus is gone.

Comment: @jfriend00: A div, last I heard, cannot embed infomation into the middle of an underlying input.  Unless you mean have two copies of said information on the page (which is a fairly ugly way to go about doing this), I don't see how this would function.

Comment: You create a separate div and use absolute positioning to position it over the top of the INPUT (the positioning can be done entirely with CSS using a common parent container) so when you're displaying the non-numeric data in the div (and thus the div is visible), then the data actually in the input is hidden behind it.  What you're asking for is a violation of typed input tags so this is a work-around.  It's a solution.  If you don't like it, then feel free to find some other solution.  It sounds to me like you're already trying to have two representations of the data anyway.

Comment: As a side note: according to caniuse.com, the `input type="number"` was [not supported on FF until version 35](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number) (although other sites mention earlier versions)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use `<input>`, you might have some success using a `<div>` with the `contentEditable` attribute set to `true`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div style="height: 50px; width: 570px; border: 1px solid black;" id="storagememory" contentEditable="true"></div>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('storagememory').addEventListener('blur', function() {
      document.getElementById('storagememory').setAttribute('type', 'text');
      document.getElementById('storagememory').innerHTML =
        document.getElementById('storagememory').innerHTML.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    });
    document.getElementById('storagememory').addEventListener('focus', function() {
      document.getElementById('storagememory').innerHTML =
        document.getElementById('storagememory').innerHTML.toString().replace(/\D/g, '');
      document.getElementById('storagememory').setAttribute('type', 'number');
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Of course, you'll have to implement some logic for the `max` and `min` constraints.

Comment: This approach has a few weaknesses.  First you have to implement logic that's already a part of the input[number] object.  Why redesign the wheel?  Second, a transition from input[number] to input[text] is (at least in my mind) less drastic than going from input to div.  Maybe I'll be forced to implement something of this sort.....assuming it doesn't bear the same flaw as noted above.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue comes from Firefox blurring the element when the type changes from `text` to `number` (probably it happens also from `number` to `text`, but it doesn't affect the element as it occurs on blur).

One possible solution for this would be to use a sentinel variable, so Firefox only blurs the element if the action that triggered the blur didn't come from the actions taken during the focus event.

How it would be done:

- Add one `data-` attribute (e.g.: `data-focus`) to the element. It will be used to keep track of when the input was focused.
- When the `focus` event is triggered, set that attribute's value to 1.
- When the `blur` event is triggered, check if the value of that attribute.

  - If it is 0, the blur was just a regular event.
  - If it is 1, the blur was caused by the input type change -> refocus the element (as the type is already `number`, it will not trigger the `blur` event again)
- At the end of the `focus` event, set the attribute's value to 0 to avoid getting stuck focusing the element.

The code would look like this (I hope you don't mind I simplified by using `this` instead of selecting the element each time, I think it makes the code a little bit more readable):

```js
document.getElementById("storagememory").addEventListener("blur", function() {
    if (this.dataset.focus == 0) {
        this.type = "text";
        this.value = this.value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    } else {
        this.focus();
    }
});

document.getElementById("storagememory").addEventListener("focus", function() {
    this.dataset.focus = 1;
    this.value = this.value.toString().replace(/\D/g,'');
    this.type = "number";
    this.dataset.focus = 0;
});
```

```html
<input style="width: 570px;" id="storagememory" min="0" max="9999" type="number">
```

You can also see a working demo on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/630gdcw4/4/

Comment: I tested this JSFiddle, and while you can enter data initially (a step up from my own code), after the first blur you are relegated to using the numeric up/down control only.  Further editing, in case the user changes their mind by a significant degree becomes clumsy at best.  It was a nice thought, though! Thank you for the attempt. :)

Comment: I've tried different things on FF30, but it doesn't like the change text->number. I'll give it one more try later, but with FF30 not fully supporting the number input, and being used by less than a 0.5% of the users I feel it's not even worth it. Is there any reason why you are not updating and still using an old FF version (client's request)?